# Retrive the data from my-sql database within last 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the database table with the following details:

```
Column Number | Column name | Data type
---------------------------------------------
1             | cardid      | int(5)
2             | price       | decimal(5,2)
3             | isbuyprice  | int(1)
4             | date        | date
5             | time        | time
```

Now, i want to retrieve the data which is inserted into the table in the last 30 minutes. I tried using the following code but it retrieved me all the rows of my table:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time > (now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time > (time(now()) - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) 
 and date=CURDATE()";
```

the best solution will be if you able to change your db table then change date field to timestamp and remove time field. then the above query will work. otherwise use the below code with your current db structure.

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time > time(time(now())-interval 30 minute) 
 and date=CURDATE()";
```

think it will work. thanks.

Comment: No this won't work, e.g. when NOW() is `2013-02-10 00:15:00` it will not return the last 30 minute rows.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separated fields, one for the date and one for the time, so you could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) + TIME_TO_SEC(time) >=
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) will convert `date` to seconds since 1970-01-01, we add the seconds of the time part with `time_to_sec`, and we compare the result with `NOW()-INTERVAL 30 MINUTE`, converted to seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time BETWEEN CURTIME() AND  TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))
```

hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE date=CURDATE() AND TIME_TO_SEC(time) > TIME_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIME()) - 1800
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table1 where concat (date, ' ', time) > ( now() - interval 30 minute)
```